# PHP MVC url splitter

Tags: php

What does this statement means in php url splitter ?

```
if(isset($this->url_param_3))
{
  $this->url_controller->{$this->url_action}($this->url_param_1, $this->url_param_2, $this->url_param_3);
}
```

Comment: It calls a method which name is contained in  `$this->url_action` with the 3 parameters `$this->url_param_1, $this->url_param_2, $this->url_param_3`

Comment: Something like this: `function foo($arg1, $arg2) {} $function = 'foo'; {$function}('firstarg', 'secondarg');`